# Executing curl command in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

can any one tell me how to write this command in ruby

```
curl -i -u USERNAME https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPOSITORY/forks
```

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/taf2/curb

Comment: @Santhosh thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [Hurley](https://github.com/lostisland/hurley).

First install the gem:

```
$ gem install hurley
```

And then run this one:

```
require "hurley"
require "json"

client = Hurley::Client.new "https://api.github.com"

repository = {
  username: "repo_username",
  name: "repo_name",
}

authentication = {
  username: "XXX",
  password: "YYY",
}

response = client.get("/repos/#{repository[:username]}/#{repository[:name]}/forks") do |req|
  req.header[:accept] = "application/vnd.github.preview+json"
  req.url.user = authentication[:username]
  req.url.password = authentication[:password]
end

puts JSON.parse(response.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [HttpParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) this help you send `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` Requests to remote server, You can send `Authentication` and Send `URL Data` or `Post data`.

For your case it will be after adding the Gem to your Gem File:

```
response = HTTParty.get("https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPOSITORY/forks",
                         body:{}, 
                         basic_auth: {username: 'USERNAME', password: 'PASSWORD'}
                        )

if response && response.body
  # parse to json if you know that the responce is json otherwise work with the response whatever you want to do.
  json=JSON.parse(response.body)
end
```

Body is a hash if you want to send any data in your case its empty no data to send, and `Basic Auth` to send `username and password` you should replace `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` with your username and password.

Answer (score 0):

By avoiding external dependencies, you can also stick with plain old `Net::HTTP`:

```
require "net/http"

username = "USERNAME"
password = "PASSWORD"
repository = "REPOSITORY"

url = "https://api.github.com/repos/#{username}/#{repository}/forks"
uri = URI.parse(url)
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https") do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Head.new(uri)
  request.basic_auth(username, password)
  response = http.request(request)
  puts response.to_hash.inspect
end
```

and if you have enabled TFA (Two-Factor Authentication), as you should, you can create an *access token* as described [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#working-with-two-factor-authentication) and use it instead of the password.